# What does MediaRecorder: start failed -1 mean?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Couldn't find what the MediaRecorder: start failed -1 error message means.

I'm getting it when I call MediaRecorder.start();

Thankyou for your time.

```
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/MediaRecorder(20600): start failed: -1
11-17 20:01:49.726: W/dalvikvm(20600): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.cording.RecordTab.onMyButtonClick(RecordTab.java:64)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    ... 11 more
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.cording.Recorder.start(Recorder.java:130)
11-17 20:01:49.726: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

1. preparing the clip first
2. ensure there's no active recording

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only get the error when I go from one activity to another when recording, not when I stop the recording on my recorder activity then go to the other activity.

Comment: Found out it is still recording when I go between activities still, didn't realise that. Saw the recording on my LogCat. Thanks for the info